# GRPC: How to send and receive async

Tags: c#, grpc

I am trying to get response from grpc without blocking.

Service

```cs
public override async Task StreamingBothWays(IAsyncStreamReader<HelloRequest> requestStream,
    IServerStreamWriter<HelloReply> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
{
    var random = new Random();
   
    await foreach (var message in requestStream.ReadAllAsync())
    {
        var r = random.Next(1, 5);
        Debug.WriteLine($"Requested {message.Name}");
        await responseStream.WriteAsync(new HelloReply
        {
            Message = $"Name {message.Name} Recvd at: {DateTime.Now} Wait For {r} seconds",
        });
        Debug.WriteLine($"Responsed {DateTime.Now}");
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(r));
    }
}
```

Client

```cs
internal class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        var items = new List<string>();
        for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            var sent = $"{i}";               
            items.Add(sent);
        }

        await DoRequest(items);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static async Task DoRequest(List<string> items)
    {
        using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://xxxxxxx:yyyy");
        var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
        Console.WriteLine("Starting background task to receive messages");
        using var call = client.StreamingBothWays();
        var readTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await foreach (var response in call.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{response}, {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            }
        });

        //sending
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Sending {item}");
            await call.RequestStream.WriteAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = item });
        }

        await call.RequestStream.CompleteAsync();
        await readTask;
    }
}
```

I am getting output like this :

```
Starting background task to receive messages
Sending 1
Sending 2
Sending 3
Sending 4
Sending 5
Sending 6
Sending 7
Sending 8
Sending 9
Sending 10
{ "message": "Name 1 Recvd at: 5/20/2022 2:31:26 AM Wait For 4 seconds" }, 6 ==> Item 1
{ "message": "Name 2 Recvd at: 5/20/2022 2:31:30 AM Wait For 1 seconds" }, 6 ==> Item 2
{ "message": "Name 3 Recvd at: 5/20/2022 2:31:31 AM Wait For 1 seconds" }, 9
{ "message": "Name 4 Recvd at: 5/20/2022 2:31:32 AM Wait For 2 seconds" }, 9
{ "message": "Name 5 Recvd at: 5/20/2022 2:31:34 AM Wait For 4 seconds" }, 6
{ "message": "Name 6 Recvd at: 5/20/2022 2:31:38 AM Wait For 4 seconds" }, 9
{ "message": "Name 7 Recvd at: 5/20/2022 2:31:42 AM Wait For 2 seconds" }, 9
{ "message": "Name 8 Recvd at: 5/20/2022 2:31:44 AM Wait For 4 seconds" }, 6
{ "message": "Name 9 Recvd at: 5/20/2022 2:31:48 AM Wait For 2 seconds" }, 13
{ "message": "Name 10 Recvd at: 5/20/2022 2:31:50 AM Wait For 2 seconds" }, 13
Press any key to exit...
```

What do I need to do to get the response for Item 2 without getting blocked by the response of Item 1?

Comment: If you want the behavior of getting responses to each separate request ASAP, then you need to make separate requests and responses and not streams.

Comment: What Ray said is right, if you want an instant response for each message just use normal RPCs, not streams. Also, your comment "I am trying to get response without blocking" makes me think that you think that there is a blocked thread who first sends all requests and the awaits the responses. But that is not true, the reason you get all responses later is simply this line: await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(r)); You send all requests immediately, but the service task gets delayed after each incoming request.

Comment: Check out the "mailer" example of this [c# gRPC examples github repo](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/tree/master/examples#mailer), I think it might be exactly what you are trying to implement, its also using a bi-directional stream, where the server reacts to each incoming call from a client.